# Trying to write a discord bot with Pycord, implementing cogs and the bot wont go online. Bot hosted with Heroku

Tags: python, github, heroku, discord, pycord

This is the main code(note that I've deliberately excluded the bot token for this question, and that isn't the source of error):

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
import random
import asyncpraw
import os
import sys

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")


@bot.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
        bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

@bot.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
        bot.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

@bot.command()
async def reload(ctx, extension):
        bot.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')
        bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

for filename in os.listdir(r".\cogs"):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
                bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
bot.run(<TOKEN>)
```

and this is one of the cogs I've created:

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

class Help(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        
    
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Help Cog Online')

    @commands.command()
    async def helpme(self, ctx):
            emb = discord.Embed(title = 'Help Page!', color = 0xeb4034)
            emb.add_field(name = "====================================",
                                  value = "-----------------------------------------------------------", inline= False)
            emb.add_field(name = "BASIC COMMANDS", value = 'Basic', inline= False)
            emb.add_field(name = "Hello", value = '>hello', inline= True)
            emb.add_field(name = "Rick", value = '>rick', inline= True)
            emb.add_field(name = "Counter +1", value = '>inc', inline= True)
            emb.add_field(name = "Counter -1", value = '>dec', inline= True)
            emb.add_field(name = "Show Count", value = '>showc', inline= True)
            emb.add_field(name = "Reset Counter", value = '>reset', inline= True)
            emb.add_field(name = "====================================",
                                  value = "-----------------------------------------------------------", inline= False)
            emb.add_field(name = "REDDIT COMMANDS", value = 'Share SR Posts', inline= False)
            emb.add_field(name = "Memes", value = '>meme', inline= True)
            emb.add_field(name = "IndianDankMemes", value = '>dankmeme', inline= True)
            emb.add_field(name = "ChemicalReactionGifs", value = '>reaction', inline= True)
            emb.add_field(name = "Facts", value = '>fact', inline= True)
            emb.add_field(name = "PerfectTiming", value = '>wowpics', inline= True)
            emb.add_field(name = "Cute Dogs", value = '>doggie', inline= True)
            emb.add_field(name = "Cute Cats", value = '>kitty', inline= True)
            emb.add_field(name = "Cute Ducks", value = '>duckie', inline= True)
            emb.add_field(name = "Aww", value = '>aww', inline= True)
            emb.add_field(name = "====================================",
                                  value = "-----------------------------------------------------------", inline= False)
            emb.add_field(name = "SASS COMMANDS", value = 'Be sassy', inline= False)
            emb.add_field(name = "Roast Someone", value = '>roast @user', inline= True)
            emb.add_field(name = "Slap Someone", value = '>slap @user', inline= True)
            
            await ctx.send(embed = emb)
            
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Help(bot))
```

I'm not too sure that the *path* is correct, as I'm using GitHub, and I'm kind of new to it...
The bot won't go online when I'm using GitHub, and hosting it on Heroku.
However, it does run when I run these files *locally*
I've tried all sorts of paths for GitHub, none seem to make a difference.
Note: I have the required Procfile, and requirements files in my GitHub repo

EDIT: Heroku Logs

```
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
-----> Python app detected
-----> Using Python version specified in runtime.txt
 !     Python has released a security update! Please consider upgrading to python-3.8.13
       Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
-----> No change in requirements detected, installing from cache
-----> Using cached install of python-3.8.5
-----> Installing pip 21.3.1, setuptools 57.5.0 and wheel 0.37.0
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> worker
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 54.8M
-----> Launching...
       Released v6
       https://test-0510.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

EDIT 2:
[This is what I get on clicking 'VIEW' after build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMcSE.png)

EDIT 3: I believe these are my logs:

````
2022-04-09T07:45:32.083418+00:00 app[api]: Deploy fd1e17a7 by user ishnkshyp@gmail.com
2022-04-09T07:45:32.083418+00:00 app[api]: Release v10 created by user ishnkshyp@gmail.com
2022-04-09T07:45:32.643569+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-04-09T07:45:35.329607+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `python ChimkenBotTest.py`
2022-04-09T07:45:35.935258+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-04-09T07:45:37.115367+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-04-09T07:45:37.115431+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "ChimkenBotTest.py", line 25, in <module>
2022-04-09T07:45:37.115679+00:00 app[worker.1]:     for filename in os.listdir(r"ChimkenBot/cogs"):
2022-04-09T07:45:37.115760+00:00 app[worker.1]: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ChimkenBot/cogs'
2022-04-09T07:45:37.282695+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-04-09T07:45:37.403838+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2022-04-09T07:45:37.453014+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-04-09T07:45:40.235384+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `python ChimkenBotTest.py`
2022-04-09T07:45:40.898743+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-04-09T07:45:40.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-04-09T07:45:41.890588+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-04-09T07:45:41.890609+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "ChimkenBotTest.py", line 25, in <module>
2022-04-09T07:45:41.890668+00:00 app[worker.1]:     for filename in os.listdir(r"ChimkenBot/cogs"):
2022-04-09T07:45:41.890686+00:00 app[worker.1]: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ChimkenBot/cogs'
2022-04-09T07:45:42.039935+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-04-09T07:45:42.174315+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed```
````

Comment: Could you share your `heroku logs --tail`?

Comment: @3nws I've just done that

Comment: This isn't it. This is from the push. We can't see why it crashed.

Comment: @3nws could you explain what you would like me to do? Because the build succeeds every time, but I cant seem to access ```heroku logs --tail```

Comment: @3nws Hi! I'm back. I think I've shared the correct logs with you, ask required. Could you shed some light as to what i should do?

Comment: Did you by any chance use `git commit -am` while committing your changes?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out.
The issue was in the *path* I'd specified.
I was going for `./cogs`
I changed it to `cogs`, and it worked.